# Azure upload blob with SAS, correct?

Tags: azure

Just wanted to ask a quick question.

I want users to upload blobs **directly** to blob storage. Heres what I came up with:

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)

    CloudBlobContainer blobContainerSas = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(blobSasUri));
    CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainerSas.GetBlockBlobReference(BLOBNAMEHERE);
    blob.UploadFromStream(file.InputStream);
```

Before this code i set the blobSasUrl, (I left that part out).

I was wondering if blob.UploadFromStream(file.InputStream); is correct? Am i uploading directly now?

Im using SAS URI for the uploading **blob**, (not container). Is this even possible? The blob isnt even uploaded yet... Should i be using SAS URI for container instead? //Confused

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in the example above your users are not directly uploading files in the storage account. They are uploading a file from their browsers to your web server by calling `Upload` action which in turn uploads the data into storage.

To directly upload the data into storage via client browser, you would need to make use of concepts like `CORS` and `AJAX`. First you would need to enable CORS on your storage account. This is a one time operation which you would need to do so that browsers can directly interact with your storage.

When setting up CORS Settings, you could start with the following CORS settings:

**Allowed Domains**: your website address (you could also specify * which would mean all websites have access to your storage. Could be recommended if you're really starting out but once you have grasped the concepts, you should always specify very specific website addresses)

**Allowed Methods**: PUT, POST (this indicate the HTTP verbs you would be using in your JavaScript AJAX calls)

**Allowed Headers**: * (* means all headers sent by browsers are allowed. You should stick to that as different browsers tend to send different headers which makes debugging quite hard)

**Exposed Headers**: * (* means all headers will be sent by storage service to the browser)

**Max Age in Seconds**: 3600

Once CORS is enabled, you could write an application where using JavaScript/AJAX your users will directly upload a file in your storage account.

You may want to read this blog post about understanding CORS concepts in Azure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn535601.aspx.

I have also written a blog post about Azure and CORS where I have demonstrated uploading a file from browser using JavaScript/AJAX which you can read here: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/12/01/windows-azure-storage-and-cors-lets-have-some-fun/

For configuring CORS rules, you may find this free utility developed by my company useful: http://blog.cynapta.com/2013/12/cynapta-azure-cors-helper-free-tool-to-manage-cors-rules-for-windows-azure-blob-storage/

Comment: Hi and thank you once again!
Im having problems with your examples.
The first one, where you upload without splitting the files into chunks, the progress sits on Progress: 0.00 % and doesnt move, but everything else works. On your other example, where you split blob to chunks, nothing works. When i press the upload button it just gives me an error: Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length" jquery-1.8.2.js:8423
PUT http://localhost:62035/UPLOADEDFILENAME&comp=block&blockid=YmxvY2stMDAwMDAy 404 (Not Found) 
It doesnt matter if i give it the right or wrong sas url, its the same error message.

Comment: My idea about my download function is listing all the belonging blobs to the user in a view, where the user can click on one of the blobs and so redirect the user to a action where all the download magic happens. In your example all your code is in the view. Would my idea work in this situation? If not, how should i get a sasurl for every blob? I was also wondering about CORS.. Why dont you need it when you download blobs directly aswell?

Comment: Im guessing im doing something wrong with your examples.. Would it be possible to upload those two projects and share them? Thanks

Comment: For `refused to set unsafe header` error, please try again after removing the following lines of code: `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', requestData.length);`. That should take care of the problem.

Comment: Thanks that worked.

What do you have to say about my idea about doing all the stuff in a action?

Should i be using your code for uploading the blob and after its uploaded call my own action where i upload metadata for the blob?

Comment: You could certainly do all of this in your action itself like you coded. But then the upload would be routed via your servers. I thought you wanted direct upload. As far as metadata is concerned, you could very well set the blob metadata along with the upload as well. In your `beforeSend` code, you could just add the metadata headers as you're doing other headers. For metadata headers, the metadata key should be prefixed with `x-ms-meta-` e.g. if your metadata key/value is say `key1/value1`, your code should add them like this: `xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-meta-key1', 'value1');`. HTH.

Comment: One... Or two last questions, hope you done mind.. :/ Im horrible with javascripts so...

If i wanted to call a action when the upload is complete, with a few parameters, (filename, filesize), where would i put it in the upload code, (the project example where you split up the blob in chunks)?
My second and final question.. If i wanted to rename the uploaded item, like.. Adding a guid to the name, where can I update this?

Comment: No worries! 1) You would put that in the `success` part of your AJAX call. 2) You could actually use JavaScript to create a Guid and append it to the name of the file in your upload URL itself. I found this implementation of Guid somewhere on SO which I'm using in my code: `function guid() {
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = (d + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
        d = Math.floor(d/16);
        return (c=='x' ? r : (r&0x7|0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
}.` HTH